# Restore Notepad to your preferred size and position in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-registry, notepad

How to change back and restore the default size and location of Notepad window as well as font and other settings to it's previous state in Windows 8.1?

Comment: Kindly check if this article can help you: [How to Reset Notepad to Its Default Settings on Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/256137/how-to-reset-notepad-to-its-default-settings-on-windows/)

Comment: @Sunny I was aware of that article. That article didn't address my question of how to restore notepad to my **preferred** setting. It tells you to delete Notepad node so everything will be back to **default**. As I mentioned in my question, I didn't want default I was looking for a way to restore notepad to my customized settings not the default setting. The answer I provided will do that.

Answer (score 1):

- First make your preferred changes in Notepad and close it's window.
- Then open Registry Editor by <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and typing `regedit`
- Now navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Notepad`
- Then right-click on the “Notepad” in the tree and export this node as a .reg file.

[image]

Now you can double click that file whenever you want and Notepad settings will be restored back to the previous state. You can also save multiple settings for notepad this way.